# override hardcoded paths in executables

Tags: executable, portability, sandbox

I'd like to override some hardcoded paths stored in pre-compiled executables like "/usr/share/nmap/" and redirect them to another dir.

My ideal solution should not require root priviledges, so creating a symlink is not ok.

(Also recompiling it's not an option)

Comment: Another option is to override desired functions using `LD_PRELOAD`.

Comment: @Chris Down could you suggest me any ready-to-use tool?

Comment: No, but I can recommend you go and take a look at `libetc`, which has a similar goal (the source code is fairly easy to look at, all you need to do is override some file handling functions). http://ordiluc.net/fs/libetc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found [this ptrace-based chroot reimplementation: PRoot](https://proot-me.github.io/).

The bind function is just what i was looking for!

This is more reliable than replacing strings in the executable + can be easily used in scripts...

Answer (score 5):

```
perl -pe 's:/usr/share/nmap/:/other/dir/nmap/:g
  ' /path/to/executable > new-executable
```

`/other/dir/nmap` should be the same length as `/usr/share/nmap`. You can pad with `/` characters if not:

```
perl -pe 's:/usr/share/nmap/:/other//////dir/:g
  ' /path/to/executable > new-executable
```

The new path cannot be longer. You always have the option to create symlinks in `/tmp` if that's an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Reference @slm's answer ...

A third way to do this *might* be to create a chrooted sandbox environment for running the executable in which everything other than the executables you want to remap are directed to the real thing.  But it would be complicated.

But I would advise getting hold of the source code and recompiling.  (Or if this is proprietary code, paying the supplier to spin you some custom executables ...)

Comment: Recompiling can be a pain sometimes due to dependencies hell, so i'm more inclined to a sandbox solution...

Answer (score 0):

What I did in a previous life was to *carefully* edit an executable to replace strings (the replacement must be shorter, fill up with zero characters!), using a binary editor (e.g. `hexl-mode` in emacs/xemacs).

If an executable contains fixed paths, they can often be overridden with environment variables (like TMPDIR, EDITOR/VISUAL, or similar) or by giving appropiate arguments. When the path is truly fixed, I'd ask for the reason behind it. There might be security or configuration explanations, that just shouldn't be overridden. Sure, it might be just [lazyness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor), but that is unlikely with software packaged by your distribution, and presumably vetted...

Comment: can i replace absolute with relative paths this way? Otherwise i was thinking about some *sandboxing* solution...

Comment: btw this method it's a bit time-wasting and has not 100% compatibility as the executable could have ascii strings obfuscated, integrity checks, etc., so i'm keeping this as a last resort...

Comment: It *should* work. But sticking your fingers in the executable already voids it's warranty, and my comments are just from a (semi)anonimous account on a social website, so it is just words in the wind...

Answer (score 0):

There are only 2 methods I'm aware of where you'll be able to accomplish something like this.

The 1st involves creating a link in the location that has been hardcoded into the executable. So in your example a link would need to be created at `/usr/share/nmap/` re-pointing to whatever other location you want. This approach will require root privileges and will necessitate the use of symbolic links at this location.

The 2nd method would involve the use of a hex editor where you'd go into the pre-compiled executables and surgically alter the binaries adding in your own paths instead of the ones pre-compiled ones.